# How to ask for specific parameters with grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to look in `/usr/share/dict/words` for a 5-letter word that starts with `d` or `D`, followed by a lowercase vowel, and ends with `s`. I have tried everything but to no avail.

Comment: What does "I have tried everything mean"? Please include the commands you have tried in your question so we know what you have attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep '^[dD][aeiou]..s$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

- `^[dD]` - match d or D at the beginning of the line
- `[aeiou]` - match a, e, i, o or u
- `..` - match any two characters
- `s$` - match s, followed by the end of the line

Comment: Note that in my (British) /usr/share/dict/words, there are a lot more vowels than the aeiou characters (even if you don't want to consider `y` as a vowel). Also note that `.` matches any character, not only letters (it will typically match the apostrophe in the `words`  file).