# Count number of processes with ps -Af

Tags: emacs

I have to count the number of emacs processes on the machine I'm remote using, by using the command ps -Af. Where do I even start?

Comment: You can filter the output from ps though other programs. E.g. grep to search/filter for the word emacs. Example: `ps -Af | grep emacs |wc -l` (note that thse commands are **not** a correct answer to your question. This commmand finds all entries with the name emacs, which includes your own command as well as things like `vim emacs`). But it will help you get started.

Comment: If this is homework/study, then [your previous question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/how-to-ask-for-specific-parameters-with-grep) involving grep might have been a subtle hint.

Answer (score 5):

`ps -Af` is not the best approach.

The `f` option is superfluous and might trigger false positive if non emacs processes use emacs or a string containing it as one of their parameter, not to mention the (unlikely) case of a user named emacs.

I would suggest using this simpler command:

```
pgrep emacs | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do `ps -C emacs --no-heading | wc -l`

`ps -C command` output processes by command name

EDIT: `ps --help` is very interesting

Comment: Your answer is an elegant way to solve the problem, except that the OP specified (s)he needed to use `ps -Af`, not `ps -C`. (Assuming this indeed is a homework. That the hw question specified -AF and that the previous homework question was about grep. All of which are assumptions on my part).

Answer (score 2):

As Hennes said you can use a "`ps -AF | grep emacs | wc -l`" to do it. But you will have the own command in there as well. To get rid of this command(s) you can us a "`grep -v`" (or `--inverted-match`) to filter out the commands you don't want to count. So it would look like that: `ps -AF | grep emacs | grep -v grep | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

Start with first principles.

Begin by establishing what exactly the command you have been asked to use does, and how the specified options (`-Af`) work. To do this read `man ps`:

```
-A     Select all processes.
```

```
-f     Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.
```

So your starting point is the output of all processes running for your user, listed in full format. Run the command to see the full output before attempting to do any processing:

```
ps -Af
```

In order to count `emacs` processes, you will then need to pipe the output through a fitering tool to process the output and/or count the respective matches. `grep` is a good option, but for efficiency and simplicity, I would use `awk`:

```
ps -Af | awk '/emacs/ && !/awk/ { a++ } END { print a }'
```

This searches for the pattern `/emacs/`, excludes the pattern of the search itself, `!/awk/`, increments the matches `{ a++ }` and then prints the total `{ print a }`.

This only requires a single pipe and elegantly deals with the issue of not returning the search process in your count.